# How to add all combinations of two pairs of key-value to a table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query, update, mariadb-10.5

I have a database of items, as each item has a set of key-value pairs such

```
place => london
field => engineering
```

since I frequently need to find items having the same two key-value sets. I created supporting tables by storing designated `id`s for each `key` and `value`.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemKeyValues
(
ItemID int(11) unsigned,
KeyID mediumint(7) unsigned,
ValueID mediumint(7) unsigned,
PRIMARY KEY (ItemID,KeyID,ValueID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1

CREATE TABLE Pairs
(
PairID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Key1 mediumint(7) unsigned,
Value1 mediumint(7) unsigned,
Key2 mediumint(7) unsigned,
Value2 mediumint(7) unsigned,
UNIQUE INDEX(Key1,Value1,Key2,Value2),
PRIMARY KEY (ItemID,KeyID,ValueID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1

CREATE TABLE ItemPairs
(
PairID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
ItemID int(11) unsigned,
PRIMARY KEY (PairID,ItemID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1
```

*(I removed indices and FKs for simplicity)*

For example, one row of the table `Pairs` is

```
PairID    Key1             Value1            Key2              Value2
1         3 (for place)    88 (for London)   10 (for field)    9 (for engineering)
```

I need to fill the last two tables.

1. How can I `INSERT` all combinations of `Key1,Value1,Key2,Value2` from the table `ItemKeyValues (KeyID,ValueID)`?
2. How can I `UPDATE` table `ItemPairs` from the table `ItemPairs`?

The performance is of great importance since table `ItemKeyValues` is over 100M rows (though, this is one-time operation).

Comment: 1) Join 2 copies of `ItemKeyValues`. 2) Update self??

Comment: Specify precisely DBMS and its version. PS. `ItemPairs` table is excess - `Pairs` may refer to `ItemKeyValues` directly. PPS. *table ItemKeyValues is over 100M rows* How many distinct `ItemID` it stores?

Comment: @Akina I didn't get how `Pairs` can refer to `ItemKeyValues`. `Pairs` is independent of `ItemID`. Sorry, it's MariaDB 10.5. I will create the tag. There are about 5M `ItemID`.

Comment: *I didn't get how Pairs can refer to ItemKeyValues.* Add `ItemID` into `Pairs`, and you may remove `ItemPairs` at all. One-to-many does not need in intermediate table until it is an entity.

Comment: @Akina The purpose is to use `PairID`. For example, I want to retrieve all items with `place=london` and `field=engineering`. I quickly do it with `SELECT ItemID FROM ItemPairs WHERE PairID=1`.

Comment: Do you want to say that `Key1,Value1,Key2,Value2` group values has many duplicates for different items?

Comment: @Akina yes exactly. The purpose to find all items in each group of `Key1,Value1,Key2,Value2`. Since it is a large dataset, it is easier to have `ItemPairs` as a map.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to receive? the list of items where place = london and field = engineering? why just don't use an index on (KyeID, ValueID)?

Comment: Well, a solution (which looks like correct) added, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO Pairs
SELECT DISTINCT NULL, t1.KeyID, t1.ValueID, t2.KeyID, t2.ValueID
FROM ItemKeyValues t1
JOIN ItemKeyValues t2 USING (ItemID)
WHERE t1.KeyID < t2.KeyID;
```

```sql
INSERT INTO ItemPairs
SELECT t1.PairID, t2.ItemID
FROM Pairs t1
JOIN ItemKeyValues t2 ON t1.Key1 = t2.KeyID 
                     AND t1.Value1 = t2.ValueID
JOIN ItemKeyValues t3 ON t1.Key2 = t3.KeyID 
                     AND t1.Value2 = t3.ValueID 
                     AND t2.ItemID = t3.ItemID;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baea6705a124652173003151e8c4bf58)

PS. I have simplified your structures by removing indices and options.

PPS. Your DDL scripts pack contains at least 1 error (copypaste misprint?).